# Visual studio 2017 references Yellow triangle

Tags: visual-studio, reference

After downloading a project from Bitbucket, I opened the project and all my references now have yellow triangles next to them and obviously the project wont compile. I suspect is must be a path issue, but I don't know where to start looking.[Screenshot of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn79L.png). How do I get the project to "see" my references? They definitely are present on my computer. Someone suggested its a .net version issue, but I have ruled that out. 
Thanks, Luke.

Comment: try building. It should say a bit more what is the issue

Comment: The build just says that the references are missing. I solved the problem by starting a new project, then just copied the folders and files I needed back into the project and rebuilt. All now working. Will never know what caused that.. one of life's mysteries.

Comment: Chances are that VS shows yellow triangles on references although it builds successfully effected projects. After such successfull builds it's possible to get rid of those triangles simply by clicking on one of the yellow references. Seems that VS needs this "trigger" to resolve all references for its UI.